# Minimal lock positions

Tags: polynomials

There are 1500 students in a school, each student requires a lock. The locks have n different positions and require three numbers to open. What is the smallest number that n can be so that every student has a unique combination?

$$
n(n-1)(n-1) > 1500
$$

How do I solve this third degree polynomial?

Comment: Why isn't it $$n^3 > 1500$$?

Comment: It's not exactly $$n^3$$ but it should be an inequality, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring that the second and third numbers be different from the preceding ones.  You are not guaranteed an exact solution, so start with $\sqrt[3]{1500}$ and adjust as necessary.